# Purpose of including types in generic instantiation?

Tags: java, generics

As an example, I don't understand the difference between

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Comment: The only difference is that before Java 1.7, the Java compiler wasn't smart enough to do the first option, and so you had to do the second. People found that to be a pain, so the Java designers introduced the first option. There's no reason not to use it when it works.

Comment: There isn't one. Originally when generics were introduced, you were required to provide the types as part of the initialisation, but they introduced the "diamond operator" so we no longer need to type the types, yea for us

Comment: They mean the same. Today most programmers prefer the former form.

Comment: *"... the Java compiler wasn't smart enough ..."* - Nit pick: the correct explanation is that the JLS didn't **allow** the compiler to figure it out.  The JLS specifies what the compiler is supposed to accept or reject.  It is not up to the compiler to be "smart".  (Indeed a "smart" Java compiler would be a bad thing because that leads to portability issues; i.e. when two different compilers for the same revision of the JLS give different compilation outcomes for the same source code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a difference, since starting java 7, using the diamong operator,  `new HashMap<>()` automatically does  type inference.

The advantage of first approach, is to make the code less crowded, also avoid having too long lines, which impact readability. If you use tools like checkstyles which improve code readability, there are parameters, regarding accepted number of characters per line.

Comment: I have also seen code checkers warn against redundant type arguments in the second form.